# Marketing Cloud Send Email - Reply to option

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I recently integrated Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud and trying to test the functionality. To send Email to different people, I integrated a new User from Marketing cloud and also enabled'marketing Cloud User' option in Salesforce, but the Email Id is not coming up when I try to select in 'Reply-to' field of 'Email Sends' in Salesforce. Any idea what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the E-Mail address manually in the Sales Cloud. To do this follow these steps:

1. Go to the "Marketing Cloud Connector Settings" via the "Marketing Cloud"-Tab added while configuring Marketing Cloud Connect.
2. Make sure "Alternate 'Reply-to' Options" under "General" is Enabled.
3. Click "Manage" next to "Enabled"
4. Click the "Add"-Button to add a reply-to address.

After following these steps you can use the created reply-to address for email sends from within sales cloud.